# How to Setup both Query and Non-Query in a single unit test with Moq Framework? (eg: Autofac)

Tags: c#, mocking, moq, autofac

I think I am missing something.

From [Autofac Moq](http://autofaccn.readthedocs.io/en/latest/integration/moq.html) or [general Moq](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dn314429(v=vs.113).aspx), I learn that I am able to setup Query or Non-Query in a single unit test. Here's my code:

**Non-Query**

```
var repo = mock.Mock<IRepository>();

repo.Setup(a => a.AddRange(It.IsAny<IEnumerable<MyModel>>()));
...
repo.Verify(a => a.AddRange(It.IsAny<IEnumerable<MyModel>>()));
```

**Query**

```
mock.Mock<IRepository>().Setup(a => a.Get(...)).Returns((new List<MyModel>(){});
var service = mock.Create<MyService>();
var mockResult = service.Get();...
```

So, Basically everything works fine. BUT, what if I want to achieve BOTH in a single unit test? The reason of asking is that, my table has around 30 columns, which I want to verify every single column matches with the value inserted. From the example in the Non-Query, it is only able to '`Verify`' there are something inserted, but not the values.

How to setup in such as a way that, I am able to verify my inserted values? (for every column)

**P.S.:**

Credit to answer by @benjrb

Basically what i would like to ask is, in a single unit test, how to verify whether the record inserted is the same as the one i get subsequently?

Using `It.Is` would help. Sample code:

```
  var mockData = new MyModel() { id = 1, code = "c1", value = 5};
  var service = mock.Create<MyService>();
  service.Create(mockData);
  var mockRepo = mock.Mock<IRepo>();
  mockRepo.Verify(a => a.Add(It.Is<MyModel>(b => b.id == 1)));
```

Note that, I actually need not call the 'Get function to verify, but to verify with 'Add' function

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `It.Is` instead of `It.IsAny` to assert the values with an expression like `It.Is<IEnumerable<Foo>>(x => x.All(y => y.Column1 == "bar"))` for all 30 columns by chaining `y.Column1 == "bar" && y.Column2 == 1 &&...` if you so wish. It will verify that your method was called with an object that matches the blueprint of your expression instead of any object of that type.

There are better ways of mocking a DbSet for your repository though if you're using Entity Framework. I would take a look at something like this https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dn314429(v=vs.113).aspx. Take a look at whether you're unit testing the service or your repository, you may have confused their responsibilities here.

Comment: Great to know the `It.Is`! Thanks so much :)
I would let you know after the testings